# ruby when we are passing more than 4 value in set how it arrange that value in set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
 Set.new

=> #<Set: {}>

irb(main):003:0> Set[1,2,3,4,5,6]

=> #<Set: {5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4}>

irb(main):004:0> Set[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

=> #<Set: {5, 11, 6, 12, 1, 7, 13, 2, 8, 14, 3, 9, 15, 4, 10}>

irb(main):005:0> Set[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

=> #<Set: {5, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10}>

irb(main):006:0> Set[1,2,3,4,5]

=> #<Set: {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}>

irb(main):007:0> Set[1,2,3,4]

=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4}>

irb(main):008:0> Set[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

=> #<Set: {16, 5, 11, 17, 6, 12, 1, 18, 7, 13, 2, 19, 8, 14, 3, 20, 9, 15, 4, 10}>

irb(main):009:0> Set[1,2,4,5,3,7]

=> #<Set: {5, 1, 7, 2, 3, 4}>
```

I want to know which algorithm Ruby is using to enter value in sets

Comment: Why? Are you just curious? Because this is an implementation detail you should normally not care about.

Comment: According to [ruby-dock](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) `Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates`. So if you care about the order, then you probably should use another data structure

Comment: i am agree with you but i am interested to know about internal implementation so that i am looking for algorithm basically in language nothing is generated without order i just wanna crack this

Comment: @SamarthPandey Sets are implemented on to of hashes, so this is where you have to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said *"in language nothing is generated without order"* but that isn't true. Hashes are generated without order.

In Ruby 1.9, though, additional infrastructure has been added on top of hashes to give them an insertion order that is used when iterating (meaning that even though they are stored unordered, they essentially maintain a linked list they can use when being traversed). **Since sets are implemented with hashes, they will be unordered in 1.8 and ordered in 1.9**, but you should not rely on this order (otherwise it's not a set, it's a list -- array in Ruby speak).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/840135) is a simple example of implementing a hash.

[This](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/) article discusses how the ordering is added.

Comment: here by using order i just wanna say that there can be some logic actually i  am new in ruby so bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/SortedSet.html 
SortedSet implements a Set that guarantees that it's element are yielded in sorted order

Comment: i am agree with you but i am interested to know about internal implementation so that i am looking for algorithm basically in language nothing is generated without order i just wanna crack this